# I wish to receive only links that match a specific criteria

Tags: python, selenium, web, screen-scraping

I have this Selenium code:

```py
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

link_mix = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for linked in link_mix:
    print(linked.get_attribute('href'))
```

I wish to get links that are of the form `youtube.com/contentcodexxxxxx` and not any other hyperlinks such as header links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this from many angles.

First one that is pretty straightforward is to just check for that string in the URL.

```
link_mix = [x for x in link_mix if "youtube.com/contentcode" in x.get_attribute('href')]
```

Additionally, instead of doing

```
link_mix = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

You could narrow it down by specifying an html element where the links you are looking for are located.

```
html_body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
link_mix = html_body.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

This will only find hyperlinks inside the body of the html, ignoring links in header or footer if the webpages contains them. If you know that these links can be narrowed down even further in another html element, you can replace the first "find_element". Do note that `find_element_by_tag_name` returns an exception if no such tag is found.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not provide any way of finding link tags with any filters.

Instead you must iterate through the elements you have retrieved and discard any that you do not want.

```py
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

link_mix = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for linked in link_mix:
    if not linked.get_attribute('href').startswith('youtube.com/contentcode'):
        continue
    print(linked.get_attribute('href'))
```